# Reactdom does not render a simple text

Tags: reactjs

I tried to render a simple text, but it renders nothing. I already installed react, reactdom, webpack, and bable. Any idea on why is it not working?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>React and Spring Boot</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id='root'></div>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.6.0/react.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.6.0/react-dom.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/babel-core/5.8.23/browser.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/babel">
        import React from 'react';
        import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
        ReactDOM.render(
                <h1>Test</h1>, document.getElementById('root')
        );
    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: what is the error you getting

Comment: Possible issue can be in code order. Do you have this script after DOM element with id `root`. If not try placing this code at the end of `body`. Your DOM element with `root` id may be not there at the time script runs.

Comment: Do you have element with id `root` in `body`?

Comment: @user-developer yes, i do have root, I have updated my code snippet

Comment: there is no error at all @RohitasBehera (i am using spring boot)

Comment: code has no issue...only the import part needs to simplified for the browser to understand

Comment: @TarasDanylyuk yes, the dom element is at the end of body, I updated my code snippet above

Comment: @Timothy I just posted the answer. Please check it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Removing import statements works for me. Please check the working snippet.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>React and Spring Boot</title>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.6.0/react.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.6.0/react-dom.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/babel-core/5.8.23/browser.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id='root'></div>
    <script type="text/babel">
        ReactDOM.render(
                <h1>Test</h1>, document.getElementById('root')
        );
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: yes, it works! thank you! but why is it working when the import is removed?because i got a warning in my IDE (intellij) that there are missing import statements?

Comment: Since you are loading react, react-dom and browser.min.js scripts using cdn, importing them is not required anymore.

Answer (score 0):

```
 It works...its just that import is not understood by the browser
```

```js
    
    ReactDOM.render(
            <h1>Test</h1>, document.getElementById('root')
    );
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.6.0/react.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.6.0/react-dom.js"></script>
 
 <div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: I tried your scripts for react and react-dom, but it still does not render anything

Comment: chec my  [github](https://github.com/BabuBahir/React-using-CDN) repo...i have simple react hello world app just using cdn